# Is possible to deletes history or cookies from Internet Explorer on WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

If I'm going to developing an app, which it can deletes all temporary files, history, cookies, or saved passwords from Internet Explorer, is possilbe to do that? Thank you.

Comment: What language?  Have you done any research?

Comment: I do this work in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for deleting IE history, cookies or password. The apps on Windows Phone are sandboxed and it is the responsibility of the user to do such action.